Spring security ACL with Postgres database
I'm trying to migrate a spring security application from SQL Server to Postgres. The ACLs component is giving me a hard time mostly because of a database type mismatch: the object_id_identity column of the acl_object_identity table is a bigint, but a lot of the standard Spring ACLs code is running prepared statements against it with string parameters resulting in this type of errors:
 column "object_id_identity" is of type bigint but expression is of type character varying

(SQL server was ok with this because it implicitly converts bigint to varchar)
I've been able to take care these issues by configuring custom queries to spring components (such as objectIdentityPrimaryKeyQuery, insertObjectIdentitySql, findChildrenQuery of JdbcMutableAclService) which do explicit casts on the column, but I'm having a hard time believing that this is the right solution. It would basically mean the framework hasn't been tested with Postgres. Am I missing anything?
I'm using Spring Security 5.8.8 and Postgres 16

Not a spring expert, but why does spring think this should be a varchar? Where does that information come from?

I have been facing the same issue lately. Im also using ACL with PostgresSQL.
I followed the instructions from github issue comment here
Edit your acl_object_identity table field object_id_identity from BIGINT to VARCHAR. I added mine as below.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS acl_object_identity (
   id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
   object_id_class BIGINT NOT NULL,
   object_id_identity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   parent_object BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
   owner_sid BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
   entries_inheriting BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE (object_id_class, object_id_identity)
 );

